# Telegraf - two identical records with different tags

Tags: monitoring, grafana

I’ll try to describe what I have and what I need. I appreciate if somebody will have some idea how to do it. :]

- I have around thousand servers where running different Apps. I would like to monitor OS metrics with Telegraf sending timeseries data into InfluxDB read by Grafana.
- That’s why I need to have one universal configuration file for Telegraf (you don’t want to change it on every servers).
- One app can run on different servers.

  > ```
  > server01 = AppName01, AppName02, AppName03
  > server02 =            AppName02, AppName03, AppName04
  > server03 =                       AppName03, AppName04, AppName05
  > ~
  > ```

My original idea was to have one tag in *[global_tags]* containing all App installed on the server (i.e. `APPS = "AppName01,AppName02,AppName03`). Which I'll load from ENV variables. But it doesn’t work. In Grafana [I cannot to have many values in one tag](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-create-tag-with-more-strings-enabling-filter-grafana-telegraf/8381/4) and filtering according.

Is there another way how to have one universal Telegraf configuration file and enable filtering according different Apps?

```
value=x, APP=AppName1
value=x, APP=AppName2
```

... for example make identical records with different tags.